# Eclipse Helios cannot access the specified device, path or file

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-7-x64, eclipse-3.6

I installed (downloaded) Eclipse Helios (SR2-win32-x86_64).  When I start `eclipse.exe`, I get the following error message window:

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.  You may not have the appropriate permissions to access them.
```

This link: [How to fix ""Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.." when rerun the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103678/how-to-fix-windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-when-re) is about a custom application, but it is the same message.

I changed the permissions of all the folders to write & read permissions.  And I still get the error.  I am running on Windows 7, 64-bit machine.

I run the program as administrator and get the same results.

Before installing `eclipse`, I downloaded and installed Java (jdk-6u25-nb-7_0-windows-ml.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

### Edit 1:

The `eclipse.exe` file has *Allow Full control` permission for each user listed in the "Group or user names:" box.

Comment: dumb question, but when you were changing the permissions, did you add execute permissions? **EDIT** (by "dumb question", i mean my question, not your question) :)

Comment: Under the "Security" tab, I have clicked on Allow Full Control, for each user listed in the "Group or user names:" box.

Comment: Another dumb question, from my side. Have you checked if you have read and write access to the `plugins` and `features` sub-directories? Write access is usually not necessary, unless you want to add plugins, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Something weird is going on with my system. I uncheck the "read" permissions, then click OK.  When I do a properties on the folder, the "read" permissions is still checked.  Is this a Windows-7 issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved.  The company has a utility SOPHOS which was interfering with the installation of Eclipse.